# Ionic Js - Error after update Node to 4.1.1 (Windows)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework

I've just updated Node to 4.1.1 version, now i get this error with Gulp:

```
Error: libsass bindings not found. Try reinstalling node-sass?
```

Can't find a solution. I've failed with:

- Removing node_modules and reinstalled it with `npm install`.
- Installing `nvmw`.
- Downgrading Node to 0.10.38
- npm rebuild node-sass
- npm install node-sass

I really don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rename/delete folder node_modules in project folder
2. In file project_name/package.json, rewrite:

`"dependencies": {
        ...
        "gulp-sass": "^2.0.0",`

3. Run again

`ionic setup sass`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `npm rebuild node-sass`.  If that doesn't work check/remove/update module version numbers.  Also the `n` module/cli could be useful.